# How to return Empty Node using Scala XML?

Tags: xml, scala

**Please note this question is strictly related to returning 0 or 1 elements (Node or Elem). Please don't consider NodeSeq.Empty as a solution, as that already works for functions returning NodeSeq type (0 or more elements), as solved on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879390/how-to-return-empty-node-or-nodeseq-using-scala-xml).**

I'm building an XML by pieces using different functions such as the following example:

```
<xml>
  { maybeXmlNode(param) }
</xml>
```

And trying to return an Empty or Non-empty Node (or Elem) based on the value of the param such as:

```
def maybeXmlNode(param: Boolean): NodeOrElem = {
  if(param) <someXml></someXml>
  else ??? //Empty or None doesn't work
}
```

The solution I'm using now is just defining the function type as Option[Elem] and then using it as maybeXml.getOrElse(""), but that doesn't make that much sense to me. My current usage is as follows:

```
<xml>
  { maybeXmlNode(param).getOrElse("") }
</xml>

def maybeXmlNode(param: Boolean): Option[Elem] = {
  if(param) Some(<someXml></someXml>)
  else None
}
```

Does a better way to express this exists, probably by using an Empty Node or Elem directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return Empty Node or NodeSeq using Scala XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879390/how-to-return-empty-node-or-nodeseq-using-scala-xml)

Comment: Haven't you already asked the same question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879390/how-to-return-empty-node-or-nodeseq-using-scala-xml?lq=1

Comment: No, that one was about zero to many elements, this is to strictly one or zero

Comment: What about a simple null ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same thing (years later). It doesn't seem like a real solution exists.
However I've hacked around it with `xml.Text("")` (`Unparsed("")` is similar, but pretty prints funny sometimes).

example:

```
val pretty = new PrettyPrinter(100, 2)
println(pretty.format(
  <elem attrib={Text("")}>
    {Text("")}
    <withtag thing="thang">
      boop
    </withtag>
    {"something"}
  </elem>
))
```

outputs

```
<elem attrib="">
  <withtag thing="thang"> boop </withtag>
  something
</elem>
```

This may however lead to non-obvious behavior with things like

```
def wrap(node: Node) = <wrapped>{node}</wrapped>
```

(hard to tell if one should be expecting another "empty" node back, or a wrapped element with no children). It also doesn't work with `xml.Utility.trim`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xml>{maybeXmlNode(param).getOrElse(new NodeBuffer())}</xml>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14387336)

Comment: That's a good point. I don't think there is something like an empty elem or node since node is abstract and an element needs to have a label. So an option represents the zero or one concept without including more than one.