# Filtering XML elements with null attributes

Tags: scala, scala-xml

I'm trying to extract attributes from a regular XML structure; it seems natural to first exclude the elements for which a particular attribute is missing.

I don't know why the following doesn't work (see answer for why I ever got the idea to test vs. `null`):

```
val test = <top><el attr="1"></el><el></el><el attr="2"></el></top>
test.child.filter(_ \ "@attr" != null).map(_ \ "@attr")
// ArrayBuffer(1, NodeSeq(), 2)
```

Why is the middle element still there after the `filter`?

I've confirmed it's not operator precedence:

```
test.child.filter(x => (x \ "@attr") != null).map(_ \ "@attr")
// ArrayBuffer(1, NodeSeq(), 2)
```

Alternatively (assuming this is optimized internally), how could I exclude the `NodeSeq()` elements *after* the `map` step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured this out. `filter` wasn't return `null`, but `NodeSeq()`, so that the following works:

```
test.child.filter(_ \ "@attr" != scala.xml.NodeSeq.Empty).map(_ \ "@attr")
// ArrayBuffer(1, 2)
```

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879390/how-to-return-an-empty-nodeseq-using-scala-xml) Q&A to discover how to create the `NodeSeq()` object by hand

---

I discovered my problem ultimately derived from crossing my own wires. I initially had been using the following:

```
test.child.map(_.attributes("attr"))
// ArrayBuffer(1, null, 2)
```

Which is where I got the idea to test vs. `null` originally. Of course, if I had stuck with that, my initial approach would have worked:

```
test.child.filter(_.attributes("attr") != null).map(_ \ "@attr")
// ArrayBuffer(1, 2)
```